# "rent" vs "rental" to represent property or payment

Tags: word-usage, difference

I looked for the dictionary and it seems both of words, 'rent' and 'rental' can mean the property or payment:

Rental from Meriman-Webster:

> 1: an amount paid or collected as rent
>
> 2: something that is rented

Rent from Meriam-Webster:

> 1: property (such as a house) rented or for rent
>
> 2a: a usually fixed periodical return made by a tenant or occupant of
> property to the owner for the possession and use thereof especially :
> an agreed sum paid at fixed intervals by a tenant to the landlord
>
> b: the amount paid by a hirer of personal property to the owner for
> the use thereof

But it seems there are some preferred usages of both words. For example, I found [this article](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/rent-vs-rental.1372588/). In the article, it says 'rent' is payment and 'the rental' is property.

What is a more idiomatic way to say in the following sentences using two words? (assuming we are looking for a place to stay for a while.)

1. I need to find new _________
2. For the room, I need to pay monthly _________

Comment: I've never heard the first definition given for *rental*, but that could be a regional thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that "rent" normally refers to the payment and "rental" to the space that is rented.

1. **I need to find a new** rental / rental unit / apartment to rent / place to rent / place to live.
2. **The (monthly) rent for the room is** $300.

A dialogue example:

"I need to find a new place to rent. How much is the rent for your room/apartment?"

"$300 per month. That's pretty common for a rental in this part of town."

Answer (score 1):

- I need to find new **accommodation**
- For the room, I need to pay monthly **rent**

An alternative for the former, depending on country and age, might be **digs**.

A **rental** car, property etc. is one you possess *by means of* paying **rent** (the manner of 'ownership' / residence).